# (locally X)-by-Y properties of groups

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I'm reading a paper on group-C*-algebras and have difficulties finding a definition of the following:

> Let P be a property of groups stable by taking subgroups. Let $T$ be a tree, and let $G\le\textrm{Aut}(T)$ be a subgroup such that fixators of edges in $G$ have P. Then for every $\xi\in\partial T$, the stabilizer of $\xi$ in $G$ is (locally P)-by-$\mathbf{Z}$ or locally P.

Later on there seems to be something similar going on:

> Assume that P is a property of groups with the following properties: P is stable by taking subgroups, quotients and extensions; P = locally P; every group that is (locally finite)-by-P has P

The author continues to tell me that e.g. amenability, elementary amenability and local finiteness are such properties.

---

Could anyone explain to me the two expressions à la (locally X)-by-Y, please?

Comment: If someone knows how to better tag this question, edits are immensely appreciated! I just added the tags concerning the subject of the paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A group is P-by-Q if it has a normal subgroup with property P such that the quotient has Q.

(Assuming that P passes to subgroups): a group is locally P if all its finitely generated subgroups have P.

The meaning of (locally P)-by-Q follows.

[Note: what's above called "P-by-Q" is called "Q-by-P" by some authors, but in geometric group theory (as in the result above) the usual convention is the first one, and the statement about edge fixators you say, makes sense only with this convention.]

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea concerning the first statement? $\mathbf{Z}$ seems to be the integers. (In the paper there is no property "Z")

btw: it's Adrien Le Boudec's "C*-simplicity and the amenable radical" that the quotes are in

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{Z}$ (boldface Z) is the classical notation for integers. On the blackboard, boldface is symbolically represented by a kind of double bar, and then  in latex, this blackboard style was represented as $\mathbb{Z}$ (mathbb Z: bb stands for blackboard), which is now widely used (but $\mathbf{Z}$ is still used).